# MySQL Character set and Collation Issue.?

Tags: mysql, collation, character-set

I Have a table when i select from the table i got the invalid data as

```
mysql> select budgetID,StartDate,modifiedBy from Table_name order by budgetID desc limit 10;
+----------+---------------------+----------------------+
| budgetID |    StartDate        | modifiedBy           |
+----------+---------------------+----------------------+
|      364 | $091-24-68 27:49:32 | -9187343239835811836 |
|      363 | NULL                | -9187343239835811840 |
|      362 | $091-24-69 14:21:19 | -9187343239835811840 |
|      361 | $091-24-69 14:21:19 | -9187343239835811840 |
|      360 | $091-24-69 14:21:19 | -9187343239835811840 |
|      359 | $091-24-69 14:21:19 | -9187343239835811840 |
|      358 | �301-32-83 19:54:95 | -9187343239835811840 |
|      357 | �301-32-83 19:54:95 | -9187343239835811840 |
|      356 | $091-24-69 05:61:82 | -9187343239835811840 |
|      355 | �301-32-83 10:95:58 | -9187343239835811840 |
+----------+---------------------+----------------------+
```

i have inserted the values for budgetID=365 as

```
budgetID                351
StartDate               2012-02-01 00:00:00
modifiedBy              1055
```

but while selecting the result i am getting invalid output.

where budgetID is Primay key bigint and StartDate is  datetime  and modifiedBy bigint.

AND

```
mysql> show variables like "%character%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> show variables like "%colla%";
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

What may the issue behind this.?

when I created a table with the same structure as this table and inserted the record then the select query is showing result OK.

Comment: Your query shows "TSCStartDate" but the metadata shows "StartDate". Is this the problem?

Comment: that is same i just edited the column name for some purpose but forgot to edit here.

Comment: check both tables in the "information_schema.tables" table or with "show create table xxx" and see the differences between both tables

Comment: @golimar: there are no differences.

Comment: I assume you're running these queries from the terminal.  It may be possible that the data and the database are fine, but *your terminal* isn't reading and displaying the characters properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your default database encoding, **character_set_database=latin1**, you should force your client to use latin1.  Your client is currently in utf8 and the database appears to be in latin1.  This assumes that your table is also using latin1.

To make sure your data is stored correctly in MySQL, you can force the mysql client to use latin1.

1 **Force the Client to use latin1**

```
mysql -u root -p --default-character-set=latin1 nameofthedatabase
```

Then run your SELECT statement to verify the character formatting

```
select budgetID,StartDate,modifiedBy from Table_name order by budgetID desc limit 10
```

2 **Backup the database using latin1**

You can also dump the database using the same option

```
mysqldump -u root -p --default-character-set=latin1 nameofthedatabase > nameofthedatabase.sql
```

Then you could view the dump file nameofthedatabase.sql using a standard text editor like textpad or gedit to see if the characters are encoded correctly.

Collation is a set of rules that determine how rows are sorted and how they are compared.  Collation does not affect the encoding which is the problem you are currently having.

If both options still give you weird symbols, the import file may not have been correctly formatted in the first place.